# Remove only unused dependencies using Synaptic

Tags: linux, package-management, dependencies, synaptic

As all distros, install much unused software, so does PCLinuxOS. But when I am trying to remove this software using Synaptic, it marks the dependencies as "to be removed" too. The problem is that those dependencies are in use from other pieces of software.

For example I want to remove KDE's Dragon player and when I mark it for removal, it marks kde-multimedia, too. But this is something used from other applications, like Juk media player. Am I wrong? How to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC Synaptic only marks things that are dependent on the package you want to remove. Not the one the program depends upon (which is what I would call dependencies). So I think you wrong. `kde-multimedia` depends on dragon player and that is why it is marked not vv.

If X and Y depend on Z, Z is not uninstalled when X is uninstalled, you have to do `apt-get autoremove` for that.

But it easy to try out and reinstall when things break (through incorrect dependencies).

Comment: Haven't thought that way, seems a little weird to me, the opposite. But indeed, you are right. Thanks :)
http://packages.debian.org/stable/kde/kdemultimedia

Comment: @py_script more to the point, the `kde-multimedia` is a meta package, removing it will not remove any actual programs installed. It's just that Dragon is included in the meta package and removing any part of the meta package removes the package itself (but not the programs it installed). Also see my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/460516/85695).